# Using an intermediate result to initialise several attributes

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have a class whose constructor does roughly this:

```
class B;
class C;
class D;  

class A{
private:
  B b;
  C c;

public:
  A(istream& input){
    D d(input) // Build a D based on input
    b = B(d);  // Use that D to build b
    c = C(d);  // and c
  }
}
```

which should work fine as long as `B` and `C` have default constructors.

My problem is that `B` doesn't, so I need to initialise `b` in the initialisation list. 
But this is an issue since I need to build `d` before I can compute `b` and `c`.

One way would be this:

```
A(istream& input):b(D(input)),c(D(input)){}
```

But building a `D` is (very) costly (*)

**What's a clean way around this problem?**

---

(*)Another problem with this would be if `b` and `c` need to be built from the same instance (like if `D`'s constructor is randomized or whatever). That's not my case though.

Comment: Make `b` and `c` pointers (better `shared_` or `unique_`)

Comment: Your idea looks like a diamond structure so virtual inheritance came to my mind: then you can have a single D being "shared" by the other objects. But @Khaur's approach seems simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 you could use [*delegating constructors*](http://www.drdobbs.com/delegating-constructors/184401647):

```
class B;
class C;
class D;

class A
{
private:

    B b;
    C c;

public:

    explicit A(istream& input)
        :
        A(D(input))
    {
    }

    // If you wish, you could make this protected or private
    explicit A(D const& d)
        :
        b(d),
        c(d)
    {
    }
};
```